# Diffrence between /etc/init.d/ssh start and service ssh start

Tags: services

Please clear my doubt Diffrence between /etc/init.d/ssh start and service ssh start.
which is the best to use service command or /etc/init.d/.

Comment: It is best to use the `service` command.

Comment: @moru why service is better please tell me.

Comment: Read the linked question and find out for yourself.