# /etc/init.d/rsyslog {start | stop | restart} : Need this to work

Tags: services, init.d

I have read the answer/comments for the thread
[Diffrence between /etc/init.d/ssh start and service ssh start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566927/diffrence-between-etc-init-d-ssh-start-and-service-ssh-start).

But I need this `/etc/init.d` method to be working. I have some auto-generated scripts which invoke `/etc/init.d` method only. Could you kindly provide me some fix/workaround for this?

Comment: The old SysV method of putting script in `/etc/init.d` will still work if everything is in place. Also note that `service` is a good option in the sense that it will first look in `/etc/init` and then `/etc/init.d` for the script so if a script is only in `/etc/init.d` then `service` will do the same as `/etc/init.d/script start|stop|restart` ..what is your goal ?

Comment: @heemayl I'd be curious to know if that's actually the case though. Upstart (et al) have very different ways of monitoring the PID and status of things, so if Upstart starts rsyslog, will the sysv-init version be able to stop it? Would the upstart command be able to stop a sysv-init version?

Comment: @Oli if both scripts exist then the one in `/etc/init.d` would contain some logic that would skip it if the init is upstart/systemd..if the script is only in /etc/init.d then it would work as expected..

Comment: Hi Heemay,  thanks for your comments..well, actually I am trying to install defense4all package & this guy keeps on complaining about "Failed to start rsyslog service". After some investigation I saw it uses one auto/runtime generated script to start 'rsyslogd' through /etc/init.d. I am very new to this defense4all & I donno where to change that script (if at all possible). To me, making /etc/init.d working looked easier compared to that other option. I understand /etc/init.d is not the recommended method, but I thought there might be some workaround for this.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the insights..please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/674769/edit) your question and the mentioned script residing in `/etc/init.d`....also while responding to someone's comment please use "@name" e.g. @heemayl

Comment: @heemayl, thanks for guiding me (I am new to this site).. but I dint get why do I need to edit my question & what I should replace it with?

Comment: I could make this work temporarily (atleast my defense4all installation went fine). these changes helped me to get going. change /etc/init.d/rsyslog script (you may keep backup of your original script file) `#! /bin/sh` `if [ "$1" = "status" ]` `then service rsyslog status` `elif [ "$1" = "start" ]` `then service rsyslog start` `elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]` `then service rsyslog stop`  `fi`

Answer (score 0):

The last answer is a way to solve the `defense4all` installation problem about "Failed to start rsyslog service".This problem is caused by the bug of rsyslog (maybe, I found on the other webs), you can use `service rsyslog` instead of `/etc/init.d/rsyslog`, so you can edit the file in `defense4all` code files to solve this problem.

In  the file:

```
../defense4all/dfapp.aggregate/src/install/config_rsyslog.bash
```

change the last sentences:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog stop > /dev/null
```

to:

```
service rsyslog stop
```

and:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog stop > /dev/null
```

to:

```
service rsyslog start
```

And then rebuild the project to create .deb or .rpm files.Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You faced this problem because the rsyslog script in newer Ubuntu is written to be handled by upstart and not the traditional init daemon.

I saw your fix in the comments above. Another workaround that allows your automation scripts to continue using `/etc/init.d/rsyslog start|stop` is -

Edit the file `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` , comment/delete all instances of following code block -

```
if init_is_upstart; then
    exit 1 (or exit 0)
fi
```

Now

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog start|stop
```

should work.

For more information, see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1311810).